# Seeking free vector data on road type in Africa

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I'm looking for a database on African roads, but I want to know what type of road this is (paved, tarred, and so on) in order to assess not only the quantity but also the quality of the road network.

Does anybody know if a database of that kind already exists?

Comment: It might also be worthwhile asking the African Union if they have such a database. https://au.int/en/contact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get road data from OpenStreetMap: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles

The road data will often include [information on the surface](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:surface), i.e. whether it is asphalt, gravel, or dirt.

OpenStreetMap data are freely available and editable, but they are crowd-sourced. There is no guarantee of completeness, especially in regard to road's surface type.